# JCombo Box not updating selected item / Innerclass access

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am making a simple calculator in Java, I'm pretty new to Java but I've done a lot of work with languages like it.

The problem is, I need to have the combo box select an item and have it kept up to date, either in a place holder, or in the box itself.

This is the basic class that sets up the frame and everything.

```
  private void initComponents()
{
//TODO:make controls here
//TODO:DONE
JFrame calculator = new JFrame("Steven Seppälä");
calculator.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));
calculator.setSize(400,300);
//"calculator" is the holder for which all the
//items must attach to
calculator.add(new JLabel("Enter the first fraction('1/2')"));
//    calculator.add(new JToolBar.Separator(new Dimension(0,10))); 
calculator.add(field1);
//    calculator.add(new JToolBar.Separator(new Dimension(0,10)));    
//TODO: ADD COMBO BOX HERE
String[] operationList = {"+","-","*","/"};
JComboBox operationBox = new JComboBox(operationList);


calculator.add(operationBox);
/*Tried doing the following as well, but it just gave the index 0 consistantly
  without changeing, regaurdless of if it did change or not                 */

//    String thing = operationBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
//    System.out.println("Selected Operation is: " + thing);
//    operationCall = operationBox.getSelectedItem();

operationBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
  //DEBUGGING
    operationBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
  }
});

calculator.add(new JLabel("Enter the next fraction('3/4')\n",1));
//    calculator.add(new JToolBar.Separator(new Dimension(0,0)));    
calculator.add(field2);
//    calculator.add(new JToolBar.Separator(new Dimension(0,0)));    
JButton Cal = new JButton("Calculate");
calculator.add(Cal);

Cal.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
  //DEBUGGING
    System.out.println("Finalizing Calculations...");
    calculations();
  }
});
//sets exit conditions and the visibility of the window
calculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
calculator.setVisible(true); 
calculator.add(new JLabel(results));
//TODO: add to(?) frame
//TODO:DONE
}
```

The action listener for the Calculate button works fine, but when I compile as it is now, I get the error message :

```
FractionFrame.java:53: error: local variable operationBox is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
    System.out.println(operationBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                       ^
```

Comment: Have you tried maybe declaring it final?

Comment: where and what exactly would I declare it final? The combo box? The action-listener?

Comment: Don't make it final. Use the source object of the event.

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Did you read the answer I gave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ActionListener you can access the combo box by using:

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
```

Comment: You add that line of code to the ActionListener. Then you can invoke the `getSelectedItem()` method on the comboBox variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
JComboBox operationBox = new JComboBox(operationList);

Make it:
final JComboBox operationBox = new JComboBox(operationList);

Comment: There is no need to make it final. Learn to use the source object of the event. This is how you can start to write reusable code. All event listeners will contain the object that generated the event.

Comment: Yes, your answer is the best answer. I'm just giving another option for him so that he can learn how to read and analyze the exception. I answered this because according to the exception, it states that local variable operationBox needs to be declared final.